# Как быстро удалить файл?

Tags: java, android, c++, recovery

Пишу файловый менеджер и захотелось сделать все операции быстрее. Начал с удаления. Большие файлы удаляются медленно. Вспомнил что в recovery TWRP используется какой-то m4fast, точно нк помню. Файлы удаляются мгновенно. Как это реализовать в приложении?

Comment: `Файлы удаляются мгновенно` Чудес не бывает, ОС должна выполнить все предписанные при удалении действия - собрать сведения о том, где лежит тело (или тела, если он многопоточный) файла, пометить элементы каталога, связанные с файлом, как удалённые, пометить блоки с телом файла, как незанятые, журналы всякие обновить... скорее стОит предположить, что программа просто быстренько отображает файл как прибитый, а сама не спеша в бэкграунде инициирует его удаление.

Comment: @Akina, Это не программа, это рекавери. Если приложения работают на потоках ввода вывода, то рекавери нет. Оно работает на уровне ядра, на уровне системы. Насчет бэкграунда - нет. При удалении его нет в менеджере, а если в логкэте вывести файлы то его там нет.

Comment: Ну то есть оно самостоятельно обрабатывает файловые структуры тома. Вы что, хотите то же самое проделать в своём файловом менеджере?

Comment: @Akina, да, именно. Приложение имеет режим суперпользователя, тоесть этот алгоритм удаления нужно использовать если юзер имеет рут права

Comment: Скорее всего это не Java

Comment: Рут-права ещё не означают возможности отогнать ОС от накопителя и общаться с ним эксклюзивно.

Comment: @Akina, тут видимо надо ковырять рекавери и искать алгоритм внутри. Исходники вроде на 4пда есть, но я там не разберусь, они на C++, но точно не на Java. Пожалуй добавлю метку c++